# Scilab turns off itself

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, scilab

I installed scilab. 
Program allows me to do the following:

- navigate menus
- search blocks.
- solve a=4+7;

But there are problems

- Try to solve without ";" like a=4+7 and than hit enter: program turns off itself and no error message.
- open xcos, try to drag and drop any block: program turns off itself and no error message.

I try to run the program from terminal. It turns off again but gives following error:

```
At line 49 of file src/fortran/formatnumber.f
Fortran runtime error: Unexpected element 'i' in format
('(f',i2,'.',i2,')')
```

My System

- ubuntu 14.04 64bit
- octave and speyder are working perfectly.

Comment: A crash is everytime a bug... http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug